# C# Identify parent,child elements in XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I found this on internet.

```
string xml = @"
<food>
  <child>
    <nested />
  </child>
  <child>
    <other>
    </other>
  </child>
</food>
";

XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
while (rdr.Read())
{
  if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
  {
  Console.WriteLine(rdr.LocalName);
  }
}
```

The result of the above will be

```
food
child
nested
child
other
```

This is working perfect, Just i need to identify which elements contains child elements.

for example, I need this output

```
startParent_food
    startParent_child
        nested
    endParent_child
    startParent_child
        other
    endParent_child
endParent_food
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. All of the elements **except** `<nested>` and `<other>` contain child elements.

Comment: @Tomalak actually i want to remake XML same structure with different values... so i need to identifz if parent have child or not....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `XmlReader`, but it won't be particularly easy. You can't know if an element has children without continuing to read further, so you'd have to buffer and track various things (as `XmlReader` is forward-only). Unless you have a good reason to use such a low level API then I'd strongly suggest you avoid it.

This is fairly trivial with LINQ to XML

```
private static void Dump(XElement element, int level)
{
    var space = new string(' ', level * 4);

    if (element.HasElements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}startParent_{1}", space, element.Name);

        foreach (var child in element.Elements())
        {
            Dump(child, level + 1);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0}endParent_{1}", space, element.Name);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", space, element.Name);
    }
}
```

If, as you imply in your comment, your actual requirement is to modify some values then you can do this without any need to process the details of the XML structure. For example, to modify the value of your `nested` element:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var target = doc.Descendants("nested").Single();

target.Value = "some text";

var result = doc.ToString();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wGxHLv) for a demo of both.

Comment: woww.!! absolutely amazing...! I have spend hours on it... :)

Comment: yes Sir, but actually there may be more than 2 elements with same name ... with different parent nodes.... so is it possible ? without any detailed process ??

Comment: @jiyaali yes, you could specify the path explicitly e.g. `doc.Descendants("child").Elements("nested").Single()`. I'd suggest you read some LINQ to XML documentation or tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for this great help/suggestion and yes you are right i have to read LINQ to XML documentation. As i am working with approx 300+ elements.

Answer (score 0):

For checking child elements, your code will look something like below:

```
    System.Xml.Linq.XElement _x;
    _x = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(xml);

    if (_x.HasElements)
    {
        // your req element
    }
```

you will have to make it recursive to check all elements.